# Pandas non correct saving to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have CSV file:

```
lang
12345,it
77777,en
```

The first line is headers. My table have one column `lang`. In each of the next lines there are two values: index and value for this index.

When I am reading this table with Pandas by `pd.read_csv(path)` I am getting the next `DataFrame` structure:

```
      lang
12345   it
77777   en
```

But when I am saving it back to CSV by `df.to_csv(path)` I am getting redundant `,` before the headers in my CSV file:

```
,lang
12345,it
77777,en
```

It seems like pandas processes this comma like unnamed column, and when I am reading this file next time I am getting this `DataFrame` structure:

```
   Unnamed: 0 lang
0       12345   it
1       77777   en
```

But I want to save the first column as indexes and others like common columns. How I can save `DataFrame` with indexes in the first column?

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=0)`  set your [`index_col`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First line mimics your df example where 12345 is in the index.  Then I save that as a normal csv.  Upon reading it back in, simply set `index_col=0` to point `pandas` to read column at position 0 as the index.

```
df.set_index(df.columns[0],inplace=True)

df.to_csv('test.csv')
df_new = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=0)
```

Comment: I can only emphasize that you must use only one way from `set_index(df.columns[0], inplace=True)` or `index_col=0`